# Home page selected tab text is not visible on mobile site

Tags: bug

I can't see the Questions text in the top nav

[image: Where's the Questions text?]

Comment: try to help and get downvoted...

Comment: Just note that voting on meta sites is different. See the *Voting is different on meta.* on this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). So downvotes does not mean a bad question altogether :)

Comment: yeah I know it's different. this isn't a feature-request for people to disagree with though. anyways I'm not all that worried about it - I divested myself from this site a long time ago anyways.